# Value returned by DataBinder.Eval is being interpreted as a variable instead of a string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I'm using **devExpress** to display a grid. There is also a link in a column so that, when clicked, it displays a popup. Since there a many users on the grid, I want the popup, which is in **kendo**, to display the name of the user as part of the **title**.

Here the method responsible to display the popup.

```
function EditContactProduct(contactId, fullName) {
 /...
}
```

On the devExpress, I've the following murkups:

```
<a href="#" onclick="EditContactProduct(
  <%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container,
  "DataItem.vendorProfileUserId").ToString()) %>, 
  <%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container,
  "DataItem.vendorProfileUserId").ToString()) %>)">
 Products
</a>
```

When I look the Chrome developer tools, I'm getting the following error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: Stuart is not defined.**

With the following markup: `<a href="#" onclick="EditContactProduct(17159, Stuart)">Products</a>`.

It looks like in the page, the value is not a string but rather a variable. How do I make it a string? I've tried to add quotes, but those quotes also appears in the output creating a different type of error: Uncaught Syntax error: **unexpected token ILLEGAL**.

Any idea how to output this value as a string?

Thank for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your string into quotas:

```
<a href="#" onclick="EditContactProduct(
  <%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container,
  "DataItem.vendorProfileUserId").ToString()) %>,' 
  <%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container,
  "DataItem.vendorProfileUserId").ToString()) %>')">
 Products
</a>
```

your code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="EditContactProduct(17159, Stuart)">Products</a>
```

correct code

```
<a href="#" onclick="EditContactProduct(17159, 'Stuart')">Products</a>
```

Comment: So much for a small error. Because of all the sever side codes, I overlooked the fact that it's still html/JavaScript. Thank you so much.